# JavaFX filtering categories

Tags: java, sorting, javafx, charts, filtering

I'm writing a simple JavaFX7 application where I display data pulled out of database using a StackedBarChart. I also provide the user with the ability to filter the displayed data sets based on a specific property's value. The problem that I'm facing is that there seems to be some caching issues. Consider the following scenario

1. Initial load, display everything to the user - no filtering involved.
    Say our categories are named 1,2,3,4 and 5, and are rendered in that order (consider them sorted)
2. The user now selects a filter value. This leads to only categories 1,2,4 and 5 being on the screen (again, in that order - this is the expected behavior)
3. The user now resets the filter to "do-not-filter".

The expected output of step 3 would be 1,2,3,4 and 5, in that order. However, it is 1,2,4,5,3. Notice the category that got filtered out is added back at the end of the array instead of where it should be.

Things I've tried so far:

- Assigning a new ObservableList via Axis.setCategory. this doesn't work.
- Same as above, but also force the category list to null before hand.
- Sorting the category list. This doesn't work either.

I can't (yet) update to Java 8 - I also can't just leave this as a broken feature because this is expected to roll out to users before we upgrade to Java 8. So JavaFX 8's FilteredList is out of question (and a backport is very much annoying just from looking at the changes to ObservableList). I also don't want to entirely recreate the graph if I can avoid it.

At this point, I'm out of ideas. Any suggestions are welcome. Below is the function that populates the chart.

```
private void refreshContents() {

    this.vaguesTotal.getData().clear();
    this.vaguesDone.getData().clear();
    this.vaguesPending.getData().clear();

    this.xAxis.setCategories(null);
    this.chartCategories = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    // Already sorted here
    for (VagueLight vagueInfo : context.getVagues()) {
        if (this.categoryFilter != null && this.categoryFilter != vagueInfo.getCategory())
            continue;

        int dossiersTraites = vagueInfo.getNbDossiersTraites();
        int dossiersPending = vagueInfo.getNbDossiersATraiter();

        String vagueIdentifier = Integer.toString(vagueInfo.getId());

        this.vaguesTotal.getData().add(new Data<String, Number>(vagueIdentifier, 0, vagueInfo));
        this.vaguesDone.getData().add(new Data<String, Number>(vagueIdentifier, dossiersTraites, vagueInfo));
        this.vaguesPending.getData().add(new Data<String, Number>(vagueIdentifier, dossiersPending, vagueInfo));

        this.chartCategories.add(vagueIdentifier);
    }

    // This just sets up event handlers and styles for the series
    for (Series<String, Number> dataSeries : this.barChart.getData()) {
        for (Data<String, Number> dataNode : dataSeries.getData()) {
            initializeDataNode(dataNode, dataSeries);
        }
    }

    // This is where the "bug" happens
    this.xAxis.setCategories(this.chartCategories);
    layout(true);
}
```

Comment: you already named your options - what do you expect from us ;) It's a waste of time to stick to and mend severely outdated versions of a framework, IMO ...

Comment: I was hoping someone would have run into a similar issue and figured a way around it. Debugging has led me to find out that the categories are indeed sorted properly, but the chart just does not care

Comment: I faintly remember that there had been tons of bugs in the early implementations of charts, many related to the really bad implementations of ObservableList (not only filtered/sorted, but also the plain impl) - so if you hit something in that context, your best option is to roll your own (c&p charts and the list stack from later versions .. *cough)